# Recovering queries with teradata?

Tags: teradata

I want to be able to recover my queries that I used previously. I was wondering if there is a way for me to get them using `sql assistant`.

Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record of all your previously submitted queries should be recorded in your "history database".  If you do not see the window, try clicking the menu bar sequence `View -> Show History`. If you click on one of the rows in the **SQL Statement** column, the contents will be copied into the Query window.

Comment: +1 Thank You. I was aware of this. However, since I have updated my windows, that history was cleared in the sql assistant. I am curious does `teradata` somehow store queries in some `meta... ` table like a cashe ? Thanks

Comment: Your history file is really an external database file on your PC. Updating Windows should not have "cleared" it, but it may be in a new directory.  Search your hard disk for a file named "SQLHistory.mdb" and if you find it, copy it to the new location registered for SQL Assistant (look at "Tools->Options->File paths".  You could also change the path to the old location, but I think it better to copy to the new location.  And shut down SQLA before doing the copy, then start it back up; it should find it.